# Solr 5.0 Tika TikaEntityProcessor indexing one document

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dataimporthandler

I have a number of documents stored inside a folder which i am using tika to import them into Solr on a periodical basis.

The data-import.xml file is:

```
<dataSource name="tika" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity dataSource="tika" name="files" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
            baseDir="/home/user/public_html/files" fileName=".*\.(doc)|(pdf)|(docx)"
            onError="skip"
            recursive="true">
                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size_i" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified_s" />

                <entity
                    name="documentImport"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text"
                    dataSource="tika">
                    <field column="file" name="fileName_s"/>
                    <field column="Author" name="author_s" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="title" name="title_s" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="text" name="details_s"/>
                    <field column="text" name="_text"/>
                </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataSource>
```

What is currently happening is solr is reading all of the files, but it is only actually processing the first file, it appears that once the first file is imported, the document pointer is set to #2 and this stays empty throughout the rest of the files. Which appears to only increment on a populated document.

This is the output from solr while importing the fields, as you can see on the first file import document#1(D#1) and document#2(D#2) are created, D#1 has content and D#2 is empty.

On any subsequent rows D#1 is not created, but D#2 is and remains empty.

```
  "----------- row #1-------------",
  "fileSize",
  2161971,
  "fileLastModified",
  "2013-06-27T15:40:17Z",
  "fileAbsolutePath",
  "/home/user/public_html/files/test1.pdf",
  "fileDir",
  "/home/user/public_html/files",
  "file",
  "test1.pdf",
  null,
  "---------------------------------------------",
  "entity:documentImport",
  [
    "document#1",
    [
      "query",
      "/home/user/public_html/files/test1.pdf",
      "time-taken",
      "0:0:0.0",
      null,
      "----------- row #1-------------",
      "text",
      "blah! testing.",
      "title",
      "testing",
      "Author",
      "user",
      null,
      "---------------------------------------------"
    ],
    "document#2",
    []
  ],
  null,
  "----------- row #2-------------",
  "fileSize",
  567396,
  "fileLastModified",
  "2014-02-17T14:46:55Z",
  "fileAbsolutePath",
  "/home/user/public_html/files/test2.pdf",
  "fileDir",
  "/home/user/public_html/files",
  "file",
  "test2.pdf",
  null,
  "---------------------------------------------",
  "entity:documentImport",
  [
    "document#2",
    []
  ],
```

Can anyone tell me how i would reset the pointer on the documentImport or how i could get it to import all of the files instead of just one?

Many thanks

**Update #1:**
I have installed Solr 4.10.3 using the same configuration and its now working, I believe that this problem could be caused by a mixture of things but the most noticeable was an upgrade from Tika 1.5 -> Tika 1.7 between 4.10.3 and 5.0.0

If anyone can confirm before i move forward with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the used Tika with Solr and following is my data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>  
<dataSource name="bin" type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        baseDir="/home/user/public_html/files" fileName=".*\.(doc)|(pdf)|(docx)"
        onError="skip"
        recursive="true">
            <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />

            <entity
                name="documentImport" dataSource="bin"
                processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                format="text" onError="skip">
                <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
                <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                <field column="text" name="text"/>

            </entity>
    </entity>
    </document>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are using solr 5 or an older version?

Comment: I worked on older version. It seems there is a issue with solr 5 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7174